# absract DGRAM socket, C server and Python client, connection refused

Tags: python, sockets, unix, connection

I am using abstract DGRAM sockets (name starts with null byte).  I have a server written in C that works fine with a client written in C, but a python client (v 3.5) gets 'connection refused'

I wrote a C server that creates AF_UNIX SOCK_DGRAM IPC socket, with a leading NULL character to make it abstract, which successfully binds.

I wrote a C client that also creates a AF_UNIX SOCK_DGRAM IPC socket, which successfully connects to the abstract socket and successfully sends messages to it.

PROBLEM - I wrote a Python 3 client using the same abstract name, but I get a '111 connection refused' when it tries to connect on the socket bound by the server.

I am running the C in CLion IDE and the python in Pycharm.

I have searched a lot for an example of a C server and Python client with abstract DGRAM sockets but have not found one.  I have another set of programs using abstract SOCK_STREAM types that seems to work.  I suspect there is some subtle thing about DGRAM that I'm not finding.

```
/* C SERVER: */
/* the needed include files here ...*/

    int main()
    {
        int                 socket_fd;
        struct sockaddr_un  server_address;
        socklen_t           address_length = sizeof(struct sockaddr_un);

        if ((socket_fd = socket (AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
        {
            perror("server: socket");
            return -1;
        }

        printf ("address_length = %d\n", address_length);

        memset (&server_address, 0, sizeof(server_address));
        server_address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
        strcpy (server_address.sun_path, rcv_path);  // copy name template,
        server_address.sun_path[0] = 0;              // set leading null.

        if ((bind (socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address,
                      address_length)) < 0)
        {
            printf ("failure %d binding rcv_path\n", errno);
            printf ("%s\n", strerror(errno));
        }
        else
        {
            int     ilen;
            char    ibuf[256];

            printf ("path '\\0%s bound to socket_fd %d\n",
                    &server_address.sun_path[1], socket_fd);
            printf ("waiting for input\n\n");
            do
            {
                ilen = read (socket_fd, ibuf, sizeof(ibuf)-1);
                if (ilen > 0)
                {
                    ibuf[ilen] = '\0';
                    printf ("Got %d chars from socket_fd %d\n",
                            ilen, socket_fd);
                    printf ( " '%s'\n\n", ibuf);
    //     . . . etc
    //     . . . etc
                }
                while (ilen > 0);


    # PYTHON CLIENT: #

    import socket
    import sys
    import os

    o_path = "\0server_recv_sock"  # client sends on this
    print ("o_path:")
    print (list(o_path))           # verify leading null char

    # ===============================================================
    # SENDS on o_sock - do a connect
    # ===============================================================

    try:
        o_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        o_sock.connect(o_path)

    except Exception as err:
        print ("oh, failed again...")
        print (err)
        exit (2)

    print ("got successful connect")

    o_data = 'hope this works'
    print ("writing '{}' to o_sock={}".format(o_data, o_path))
    o_sock.send(o_data.encode('utf_8'))

    o_data = 'q'
    o_sock.send(o_data.encode('utf_8'))

    o_sock.close()
```

I see no reason why the python client cannot connect - what am I missing here?  Again, it works fine with a client written in C.

Comment: What is the value of `rcv_path` ?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  In the c code, rcv_path is '*server_rec_path', which is copied to server_address.sun_path, then the first byte is replaced with a null character before the bind call is made.

Comment: *"...rcv_path is '*server_rec_path',.."* - in this case it would be `\0server_rec_path` in the C-code vs. `\0server_rec_sock` in the Python code, i.e. these are different.

Comment: actually I mis-spoke there - they are "\0server_recv_sock" for the python client and "*server_recv_sock" for the C server before putting null in the first byte.  A line I did not put in my post for brevity, but is part of the code, is this:  static char rcv_path[] = "*server_recv_sock".  Since the C server works with a C client and a python server works with a python client, there must be some difference between the two but I cannot see it.

Comment: Both programs are short, I'd be happy to send you a tarball if you want to give it a whirl.

Comment: If I use the same abstract socket names but set up SOCK_STREAM instead of SOCK_DGRAM (with listen() and accept() on server side) it all works fine.  Must be some peculiarity for DGRAM in abstract sockets.  DGRAM works fine if using file paths with C server and Python client.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - OK, I think I've got the answer.  It seems that the length argument to the bind() function is very temperamental.  I set a variable: "hp_len = strlen(rcv_path+1) + 1", then for the lengh arg in bind I used "sizeof(server_address.sun_family) + hp_len" and it all worked.